# Display text of search area in "Results for cats" and "No results found for cats"

Tags: search, text

So i have setup search area which display different results after user is searching for something but i'm not sure how could i add text that say "No results found for (word that user search for)" or "Results found for (word that user search)". If anyone has suggestion or code that could do that please share i would really appreciate.

```
       <input
                id = "searchText"
            data-path=".title"
            data-button="#title-search-button"
            type="text"
            value=""
            placeholder="Search..."
            data-control-type="textbox"
            data-control-name="title-filter"
            data-control-action="filter"
        />
        <script>
        document.getElementById('searchText').addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
                      if(e.keyCode == 13){
                       $("#title-search-button").click();
                      }
                    });
        </script>

        <button
            type="button" 
            id="title-search-button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
```

and this is code that show up if no results are found:

```
                <div class="box no-results text-shadow align-center">
                    <p>No results found</p> 
                </div>
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: how and where are you loading the search result. in javascript you have show() and hide() functions which you may use to hide the div. You will need to add an id to the div to call show/hide. Also you may use a label to control the display of result count from search action.

Comment: The no results works fine already i'm not sure what kind of code should i add to display text that user typed in search bar.

Comment: Let me ask you it in a different way. Where are you handling $("#title-search-button").click(); THis would be a javascript code block. Wherever you doing that you can add the manipulation for your displaying result count

Comment: It's in separate file that is linked to main html.